# How do pull images from a wordpress post to display it on the screen?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display something like a thumbnail for my post. Is there any wordpress function that can do that? I read about wordpress featured images but I dont see the option to set one on the wordpress admin page.

I also tried using `the_post_thumbnail()` but it didnt work.

this is what my div looks like at the moment:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 22rem;">
          <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><?php the_title() ?></h5>
            <p class="card-text">Random Card content</p>
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Like below codes:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 22rem;">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'card-img-top']);?>

      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
        <p class="card-text">Random Card content</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

When you use `the_post_thumbnail()` dont use extra `img` tag!

Comment: Ah so that was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome brother. @RahulChatterjee

Answer (score 1):

the_post_thumbnail(); directly output the image.So please don't use echo

```
the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); 
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );


<div class="card" style="width: 22rem;">
   <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><?php the_title() ?></h5>
            <p class="card-text">Random Card content</p>
          </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found another way to do it while using the img tag

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" alt="Card image cap">
```

Comment: But above my answer is Good way to fetch img on  @rahul